# On the inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a square matrix. Prove that:
$A^{2}-A+I=0 \implies A^{-1}=I-A$

So I have $A(I-A)=I$
so $ A^{-1} = I-A $ What is next step, what I did is it a complete solution or not?

Comment: I edited your question to change the $1$s to $I$s. It is more customary in linear algebra to use the symbol $I$ to denote the identity matrix, not $1$.

Comment: Whether or not it is a complete solution depends, in my opinion, on two things: 1. Do you know that $XY=I\implies YX=I$, for all square matrices $X$ and $Y$ and 2. Does your definition of invertibility require both "left-invertibility" and "right-invertibility"?

Comment: @GitGud Why $1 = I$? $det I = 1$ but I is matrix, not determinant.

Comment: @NowakGrzegorz Hm?

Comment: $A(I-A)=(I-A)A=I$

Answer (score 0):

A has to be non singular. Since Ax=0 implies x=0 if u plug x in the matrix equation. So A is invertible. It is square so right invertible and left invertible are equivalent. The rest is just using the fact that inverse if exists is unique and I-A is already an inverse.